# When I connect to my server and use the 'htop' command, I often find multiple instances of MySQL running

Tags: mysql, server, remote-access

When I connect to my server and use the 'htop' command, I often find multiple instances of MySQL running, causing my remote system to become very slow. How can this issue be fixed?[image]

Comment: They'll be forks of the main process, which is one way of doing multithreading. Why do you think this is slowing down your system? Is it MySQL or MariaDB, and which version?

Comment: Please porst TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of this query - SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
    COUNT(*),SUM(time) as 'time - seconds',SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
        FROM information_schema.processlist 
        WHERE 
        command="Sleep"; 
  - to consider.